# why can't outputing anything before Session_Start()?

Tags: php, session

I can't figure out why ,anyone any help?

Comment: Why would you want to output anything before it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I use session_start() in my php script? It says headers are already sent.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712326/why-cant-i-use-session-start-in-my-php-script-it-says-headers-are-already-sen)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

simple: session_start sets your php session cookie, and cookies can only be set in the http header. php must send the header before it can start sending content. so as soon as you start to output content, php implicitly sends the http header and thus disables changing header values.

a common way to prevent this is to use output buffering - see http://php.net/manual/de/ref.outcontrol.php

Comment: Thanks for your reply,it is quite clear.I doubt about this question mainly because I didn't know that http headers must be set and sent before datas are transfered,so I thought why not send the header again when session_start() is called.Now I got it,thanks.