# session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter

Tags: php

I'm getting the following warnings when trying to initiate a session:

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: 
Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent 
(output started at /www/zxq.net/l/i/b/librarymanagement/htdocs/public/admin/index.php:2) 
in /www/zxq.net/l/i/b/librarymanagement/htdocs/includes/session.php on line 9
```

I've made sure all white space is clear, `session_start()` should be the first thing being called. I don't think anything else is being sent before `session_start()` is called.

Here is my code:

```
class Session {
    private $logged_in=false;
    public $user_id;
    public $message;
    function __construct() {
        session_start();
        $this->check_message();
        $this->check_login();
        if($this->logged_in) {
        } else {
        }
    }

    public function is_logged_in() {
        return $this->logged_in;
    }
    public function login($user) {
        if($user) {
            $this->user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user;
            $this->logged_in = true;
        }
    }  
    public function logout() {
        unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
        unset($this->user_id);
        $this->logged_in = false;
    }
    public function message($msg="") {
        if(!empty($msg)) {
            $_SESSION['message'] = $msg;
        } else {
            return $this->message;
        }
    }
    private function check_login() {
        if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
            $this->user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
            $this->logged_in = true;
        } else {
            unset($this->user_id);
            $this->logged_in = false;
        }
    }  
    private function check_message() {
        if(isset($_SESSION['message'])) {
            $this->message = $_SESSION['message'];
            unset($_SESSION['message']);
        } else {
            $this->message = "";
        }
    }

}
```

Here is how it is used:

```
$session = new Session();
$message = $session->message();
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Could you send not only the code part. But the script from the top until the first call to the method that tries to set the header. And please format the code (select it and click {} button). Most likely you have, like the error states, something that is output before. You can add:

 ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL);
 ini_set("display_errors", 1);

Comment: This is close, but not identical to several similar questions, you'll see them at the right side of the page. I've made some edits to your question, please take note of them for future reference when asking questions on Stack Overflow. Again, your topic has been covered, but it appears that you mostly need help in your particular implementation. The community, however is free to disagree with me and vote to close this question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I use session_start() in my php script? It says headers are already sent.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712326/why-cant-i-use-session-start-in-my-php-script-it-says-headers-are-already-sen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to send headers after the body of response or in the middle part of the body, it's not allowed in HTTP...

the reason is if you start your code

```
\s
<?php
```

you space is the body part of your response...
and when you finish your code with

```
?>
\s
```

this space is output too....

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `session_start()` before sending any data to the client

Answer (score 0):

You have output before the call to session_start(). No doubt about it. Check if there is not an error message or a warning thrown before that, be weary of any whitespace at beginning of file.

Answer (score 0):

This is your error message:

> (output started at /www/zxq.net/l/i/b/librarymanagement/htdocs/public/admin/index.php:2)

Please read it.

Look at the mentioned file and line number. There is your problem.