# $_POST[] is not working

Tags: php, post

I am a novice in PHP. I am trying to execute this simple code. Taking a textfield value from one php page, I want to display it in another php page. But, it is not working. Where is my error??

**new1.php**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="welcome1.php" method="POST">
            <input name="Name" type="text" />
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
    <?php
        SESSION_START();
        $var="";
            if(!empty($_POST['Name'])){
            $var=$_POST['Name'];
        } else {
            $var="NOT SET";
        }
        $_SESSION['name11']=$var;
    ?>
</html>
```

**welcome1.php**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
        session_start();
        $n="";
        if(isset($_SESSION['name11'])){
            $n=$_SESSION['name11'];
            echo $n;
        } else {
            echo "no session";
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Answer is given by Montycarlo below. I would like to suggest that `session_start()` should be the first line of the page, it is a good practice and makes debugging easier. Also please read more on `sessions` and `forms` in PHP.

Comment: Whats with all the suffix `1`'s

Comment: and it is not showing any error ?????

Comment: @PrasanthBendra, No,it is not showing any error. But it gives wrong output. It shows 'NOT SET' in the welcome1.php page. I wanted to display the value given in textfield of new1.php. Where is my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is in the wrong file.

This should all be in welcome1.php, currently it is in new1.php.

```
<?php
    SESSION_START();
    $var="";
    if(!empty($_POST['Name'])){
        $var=$_POST['Name'];
    }
    else
    {
        $var="NOT SET";
    }
    $_SESSION['name11']=$var;
?>
```

Comment: No, exactly what I want to do is that, accessing the textfield value from one page (Here new1.php), display it in another page (welcome1.php). If you kindly elaborate your solution...

Comment: PHP does not work the way you're believing it to. It executes once, on the server side. If you follow my solution the textfield will still be on the page new1.php, but will be processed in welcome1.php.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got my fault.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong. Just because session_start() needs to be run before the headers are sent.

The solution in your case is:

Move session_start(); above < html ...

Please visit:
[Why can't I use session_start() in my php script? It says headers are already sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712326/why-cant-i-use-session-start-in-my-php-script-it-says-headers-are-already-se)

Comment: No, it's still not working. I've placed the script part above all. `<?php session_start();....` The else part of new1.php is executing. So, in welcome1.php it is showing 'NOT SET". This was not the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is because you are posting the form to welcome1.php (action of your form) and code to get the post value is in new1.php.

Change you files to :

**new1.php**

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="welcome1.php" method="POST">
            <input name="Name" type="text" />
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**welcome1.php**

```html
<?php
    session_start();
    $var="";
    if(!empty($_POST['Name'])){
        $var=$_POST['Name'];
    } else {
        $var="NOT SET";
    }
    $_SESSION['name11']=$var;

    echo $_SESSION['name11']; /// you get this $_SESSION['name11'] in all the pages.
?>
```

Comment: I suggest you to go through the basics of form submission and sessions, refer http://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: In stack we say thanks by accepting the answer and voting up :D